# Does a procedure declared in package requires separate creation outside it?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, package, plsqldeveloper

I am new to creating packages, I have to include a procedure and a function in a package,

1. I will create a package by declaring its head and body, Body will contains details about procedure and function.

My query is, after package is created, do I need to create that procedure and function again outside? i.e Create and Replace procedure ...and all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You just define the procedure in the package body.

A procedure can either be a stand-alone procedure or it can be part of a package.  In real systems, you almost never want to have stand-alone procedures.  It virtually always makes sense to put related procedures together into packages to better organize them.